# Compile error have tried to fix, to no success

Tags: java, string, compiler-errors

I am in an entry level Java class and we have been assigned a Team Competition project.  I have completed it for the most part but when I compile it I get a few errors stating:

```
3 errors found:
File: C:\Users\Brett\Documents\DrJava\Team.java  [line: 70]
Error: The constructor Team(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) is undefined

File: C:\Users\Brett\Documents\DrJava\Team.java  [line: 79]
Error: The constructor Team(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) is undefined

File: C:\Users\Brett\Documents\DrJava\Team.java  [line: 80]
Error: The method competition(Team, Team) is undefined for the type Team
```

Source code

```
    /**
  * Project 1 -- Team Competition Simulator 
  * 
  * This program gets input from the user to make two Team objects and then
  * calculates the winner.
  * 
  * @Brett Donahue
  * @lmf 
  * @16 September 2013
  */
 import java.lang.Math.*;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Team{
   final int offense, defense;
   final double luck;
   final String name, location;
   /**
      * Class constructor
      * 
      * @param n = name of the team to be created
      * @param loc = location of the team to be created
      * @param o = offensive rating of the team to be created
      * range should be 0-100
      * @param d = defensive rating of the team to be created
      * range should be 0-100
      * luck is to be randomly generated using java.lang.Math
      * range: 0-1
      */
   public Team(String n, String loc, int o, int d){
     offense = o;
     defense = d;
     name = n;
     location = loc;
     luck = (double)(Math.random() * (1 - 0) + 0);
   }
   /**
      * Perform the calculation explained on the project description
      * Print out the ratings of each Team
      * Print out the winning Team's location and name
      * You do not have to worry about there being a draw
      */
   public static int competion(Team home, Team away){
     System.out.println(home.name + ": Offense " + home.offense + "Defense "+home.defense);
     System.out.println(away.name + ": Offense " + away.offense + "Defense "+home.defense);
     double ovr1 = (1/25.0)*(home.offense+home.defense+(0.2*(home.offense+home.defense))*home.luck) + 0.4;
     double ovr2 = (1/25.0)*(away.offense+away.defense+(0.2*(away.offense+away.defense))*away.luck) + 0.4;
     if(ovr1 > ovr2)
       System.out.println("The "+home.name+" of "+home.location+" have won!");
     else if(ovr1 < ovr2)
       System.out.println("The "+away.name+" of "+away.location+" have won!");
     return 0;
   }
    /**
      * Prompt user for input
      * Formatting = prompt "Name Location Offense Defense"
      * Make two Team objects
      * Compete
      */
   public static void main(String[] args){
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Team 1: Enter a Name.");
     String n1 = scanner.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Team 1: Enter a Location.");
     String l1 = scanner.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Team 1: Enter an Offensive Rating (0-100).");
     String o1 = scanner.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Team 1: Enter a Defensive Rating (0-100).");
     String d1 = scanner.nextLine();
     Team team1 = new Team(n1,l1,o1,d1);
     System.out.println("Team 2: Enter a Name.");
     String n2 = scanner.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Team 2: Enter a Location.");
     String l2 = scanner.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Team 2: Enter an Offensive Rating (0-100).");
     String o2 = scanner.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Team 2: Enter a Defensive Rating (0-100).");
     String d2 = scanner.nextLine();
     Team team2 = new Team(n2,l2,o2,d2);
     competition(team1,team2);
   }
 }
```

I have checked the class discussion board and even looked up how to fix this, but nothing has been able to help me out!  Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: `The constructor Team(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) is undefined` What do you think this means?

Comment: Consider using an IDE like IntelliJ, Eclipse, Netbeans, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You have a constructor taking 2 strings and 2 ints, but you attempt to pass 4 strings.  Convert the last two strings to `int` before passing them to the constructor.

For `competition`, it's misspelled when declared.  Change

```
public static int competion(Team home, Team away){
```

to

```
public static int competition(Team home, Team away){
```

Comment: What do you mean by last 2?

Comment: Specifically, for `team1`, `o1` and `d1`.  For `team2`, `o2` and `d2`.

Comment: But if I do that it will give me the error saying that it can't be converted from string to int...

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is defined as

```
public Team(String n, String loc, int o, int d)
```

Notice that the constructor takes two arguments of type String and two arguments as type int.

You should use the following code in the main method.

```
System.out.println("Team 1: Enter an Offensive Rating (0-100).");
int o1 = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("Team 1: Enter a Defensive Rating (0-100).");
int o2 = scanner.nextInt();
```

Always use [THIS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) as a reference.